# Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, pdf, php8, mpdf

me sale este mensaje de error al momento de intentar crear un pdf en php, me parece extraño ya que corrí el composer con la respectiva librería mpdf de forma correcta sin ningún problema pero nada:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    $mdf = new mPDF();
    $mdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hola desde mi PDF</h1><img src="https://images.falabella.com/v3/assets/
    blt7c5c2f2f888a7cc3/blt5787e34d77f3c86f/610b07153ea66f3ecbdbdb89/android-chrome-256x256@2x.png">');
    $mdf->Output();
?>
```

El mensaje me detalla que el error se encuentra en el archivo mpdf.php en la línea 2349: Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios-php\pdf\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\mpdf.php on line 2349

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error se encuentra en esa condicional, en otro foros leí que cambiando los '{}' por los '[]' se solucionaba, y es así, el problema es que en mi caso, comienza a darse el mismo error en otras líneas más y sinceramente se vuelve tedioso ir cambiando una por una porque son muchas con dicho error.¿Existirá una forma más generalizada de poder solucionar este error?

PD: mi versión de PHP es la 8

Comment: es por ser php8, revisa la version de php que las dependencias exigen, php 8 es mucho mas estricto que 7, te recomiendo bajes la version a 7.X y eso ya no te mostrara error

Comment: No tienes que cambiar nada línea por línea ni tampoco tienes por qué degradar tu versión de PHP. Si tienes PHP 8 instalado en tu entorno, simplemente actualiza `mpdf` a la última versión. [Como indican ellos en Github](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf), la librería soporta PHP 8 en su versión 8.1.3, considera pues actualizar a esa versión. Te recomiendo que uses Composer para gestionar tus librerías.

Comment: @A.Cedano revisé que mi versión actual es la 8.1.5, de ser así, no me funcionaría la librería?

Comment: [La versión `8.1.5`](https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf#v8.1.5) es compatible con PHP 8, no hay ningún problema con eso. Yo creo que el problema está en el uso contextual, quizá estás usando el código al estilo anterior a PHP 8 en alguna parte. En el trozo de código que compartes aquí el problema no aparece, pero puede que lo tengas en otra parte, algo así como un footer o un header que tienes definido en otro código. Revisa la traza completa del mensaje de error, allí debería decirte con exactitud en qué archivo estás cometiendo el fallo.